# Getting a Value in a Dyanmic XPath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors

```
 number_of_selected_players = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]").value()
 print(number_of_selected_players)
```

I want to get the value from this particular  element: [image]

But I end up getting this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

How do I fix this or can you point to me to similar questions to this, so that I can what error I made?

Thank you.

Comment: When someone post picture of code it is very difficult to write code from that. and mostly people avoid that since they invest their time for you.So if you want quick and good responses don't add the screenshot of code just add that code as part of post. so that people can reproduce your case. Please read [mcve] and follow it in every future post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following-sibling xpath command to get "0 / 15".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
    ((By.XPATH,
      '//h3[text()="Players Selected"]/following-sibling::div'))
)
number_of_selected_players = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[text()="Players Selected"]/following-sibling::div').text
print(number_of_selected_players)
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[text()="Players Selected"]/following-sibling::div"}

Comment: Can you share the full html page source or the link? Is there any iframe tag in the html source?

Comment: Can you see it?

Comment: I modified it a little. Test it.

Comment: You just attached the picture of the html, so it is a little difficult to parse the html, but send the result of my script.

Comment: login details:  arvindex777@gmail.com, pw: testcode77. You'll need to go to squad selection, and check 0/15 data. refer the pic. Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the website. My xpath works, but the error may be because of time wait. You can use WebDriverWait.  I added the part in my code.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It works. But what is the time wait? why use the webDriverWait for?

Comment: Pages take time to load so you might just miss elements without webdriverwait.